# Cakephp : Check if view element exists

Tags: view, cakephp-1.3, element

Is there a way to check if an element exists for a view? 
I want to load a different element according to a category it belongs to but not all categories have an element for it...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As of CakePHP version 2.3 you can use the View's `elementExists` method:

```
if($this->elementExists($name)) { ... }
```

In older versions of 2.x you can do:

```
if($this->_getElementFilename($name)) { ... }
```

But sadly in version 1.3 it looks like the only way is to know the full path and do something like:

```
if(file_exists($path . 'elements' . DS . $name . $ext)) { ... }
```

That is what they do in the 1.3 source code, but there is some complexity around getting `$path` from various plugins and checking each of those paths. (See link below.)

Sources:

http://api.cakephp.org/2.3/class-View.html#_elementExists

http://api.cakephp.org/2.0/source-class-View.html#722

http://api.cakephp.org/1.3/source-class-View.html#380

Comment: I tried to call this from controller but not working for version 2.4

Comment: @MohamadAli `elementExists()` is a View method so shouldn't be called from the controller.

Comment: @drmonkeyninja i need to check before rendering view How can i check it from controller ? currently i use try/catch

Comment: @MohamadAli this should be openned as a question where it would be easier to answer. Share the link and I'll have a go at answering it for you. :-)

Comment: @drmonkeyninja may you please check this question ?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31211446/cakephp-check-template-file-exist-or-not

Answer (score 1):

set element name in controller:

```
$default_element = 'my_element';
$element = 'my_cat_element';

if ($this->theme) {
   $element_path = APP . 'views' . DS . 'themed' . DS . $this->theme . 'elements' . DS . $element . DS . $this-ext;
} else {
   $element_path = APP . 'views' . DS . 'elements' . DS . $element . $this-ext;
}
if (!file_exists($element_path)) {    
   $element = $default_element;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always load an element specific to a category 'on demand' by telling it so from the controller. For example:

```
Within Controller Action:  
$this->set('elementPath', "directory_name/$categoryName");
```

---

```
Within the View (this can also be tried exactly within a Layout):
<?php
if (!empty($elementPath)) { // you can also set a default $elementPath somewhere else, just in case
echo $this->element($elementPath);
}
?>
```

In fact, there is even other ways to achieve this. If the element is going to be loaded within a *layout*, then the set() method shown above can be specified from the view itself. Or, it can even be fetched from url parameters, like:

```
Within the View or Layout:
<?php
$elementPath = $this->params['url']['category']; // note that the param array can vary according how you set the url; see http://book.cakephp.org/#!/view/963/The-Parameters-Attribute-params
echo $this->element($elementPath);
?>
```

Of course, you will always have to specify, but the same would go for checking if the file exists.