# Cakephp : check template file exist or not?

Tags: cakephp

In Cakephp version 2.4 in controller before rendering view need to check view file exist or not ? then decide to render. for example i need some code like below.

```
if( template_exist( $template_name ) )
{ 
   $this->render( $template_name );
}
else
{
   $this->render( $default_template );
}
```

Currently i use try/catch but i seek for best way.I need function **template_exist** can any one help please ?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this from the controller by creating a new View object then using [`elementExists()`](http://api.cakephp.org/2.4/class-View.html#_elementExists) to check if the template exists:-

```
$View = new View($this, false);
if ($View->elementExists($templateName) === true) {
    $this->render($templateName);
} else {
    $this->render($defaultTemplate);
}
```

This way Cake will check all the usual places for element templates.

Comment: Thank you for spending time to answering but it`s not working it always return false what ever template file exist or not i tested on direct file and also sub directory

Comment: What are you passing as `$templateName`? It shouldn't include the `.ctp` extension. Take a look at the `View::_getElementFilename()` method which `elementExists()` calls. You will see it uses `file_exists()` to check for the file. You're either passing the view file incorrectly or the file doesn't exist. It's always worth taking a look at what Cake is actually doing when you call one of its methods as it often will reveal the cause of your issue. :-)

Comment: I pass exactly what $this->render( $templateName ) can redner. It`s strange for me

Comment: I would try debugging `View:: _getElementFilename()` to see where it is failing as this should work. Perhaps there is a bug.

Comment: this won't work because it is exclusively looking for template files in elements folder `if (file_exists($path . 'Elements' . DS . $name . $ext)) {`